# Intermittent error: Name [comp/env/jdbc/app] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [comp]

Tags: java, tomcat, datasource, jndi

In our Tomcat 7 app, we **sometimes** have the following error while trying to access our DB:

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env/jdbc/app]
>   is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [comp].

Sometimes we have this error, sometimes not.

Context file:

```
<Context path="/app" docBase="/our/path/webapps/app.war" reloadable="true">
       <Resource name="jdbc/app"
            maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" username="usr" password="pwd"
            driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app" />
</Context>
```

Beans files:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/app" />
</bean>
```

Code that sometimes fails:

```
getSession().createCriteria(OurClass.class).add(Restrictions.eq("key", key)).uniqueResult();
```

Any idea why this error is happening? And why it's intermittent?

Comment: I know this is old, but were you able to solve this? I'm having this exact same issue now.

Comment: No sorry @Brandon I don't remember if/how we solved this :-/